# Including the main topic word(s) in the subject index

Tags: indexing

Is it considered good practice to include chapter/section main topic words into the subject index? Suppose I have a section on *Foobar*. It naturally frequently mentions *foobars*. Should I include any/all of them into the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a couple of examples, it looks like they usually **list all references, but group them together**.

> Foobar, 24, 38-45, 117

Just from looking at these numbers, the reader will be able to tell that they'll get more information about foobars in the longer section (possibly a chapter) starting at page 38.